# Excel Barcodes easily substract or add number

Tags: excel

I have this in my table:

```
Column A      Column B        Column C            Column D
Galaxy S1        5           BARCODE ADD       BARCODE SUBSTRACT       
Galaxy S2        4           BARCODE ADD       BARCODE SUBSTRACT
Galaxy S3        2           BARCODE ADD       BARCODE SUBSTRACT
```

So what I want is that for example you scan the barcode add for the Galaxy S1 that in Column B the 5 becomes a 6.

When you do the barcode add for Galxy S3 the 2 becomes a 3

Same with substract only subscract it from column b

All the barcodes are different.

Hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called `PROD_INVENTORY` and your columns are called `PRODUCT`, `INVENTORY`, `CODE_ADD` and `CODE_SUBTRACT`, you could achive it like so:

```
UPDATE PROD_INVENTORY
    SET INVENTORY = INVENTORY + 1
    WHERE CODE_ADD = :code;
UPDATE PROD_INVENTORY
    SET INVENTORY = INVENTORY - 1
    WHERE CODE_SUBTRACT = :code;
```

`:code` is the barcode number you have scanned. Depending on the scanned code, one of the statements will update a single row, the other statement won't update anything.